# Views taxonomy for multiple content types

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have three different content types: News, Events and Resources. They all use the same set of taxonomy so that all content is tagged with the same categories.

I want to build a view with the taxonomy terms exposed so that they can be searched by users.

However, I seem to have to add each as a separate field, which looks quite messy.

I've tried a grouped filter, however, no results are found when I know they exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using views :

1. Create a new view with show content of type ALL -> continue and edit
2. Under format select show fields
3. Under filter criteria select Content: Has taxonomy term and select selection type Drop down later check Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it and click apply

Result : You can have an exposed filter with taxonomy term that filters the contents irrespective of content type

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new field referencing the terms per content type or did you add an existing field to each content type?

If you create the field once and add it to many content types, it works in views. As long as you have no content type filters in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a bug in the views filter that it won't show content from multiple content types using the same taxonomy tag unless the content is tagged as "published" regardless of how the view is configured for the published flag.